# updating django project: changing html form method from GET to POST

Tags: html, django, forms, post

I am new to django and have made a method:GET form with checkboxes/text boxes and a submit button. I want to change it to a method:POST form but keep getting the error that says:

> Reason given for failure:
>
> CSRF token missing or incorrect.
>
> In general, this can occur when there is a genuine Cross Site Request Forgery, or when Django's CSRF mechanism has not been used correctly. For POST forms, you need to ensure:
>
> Your browser is accepting cookies.
>
> The view function uses RequestContext for the template, instead of Context.
>
> In the template, there is a {% csrf_token %} template tag inside each POST form that targets an internal URL.
>
> If you are not using CsrfViewMiddleware, then you must use csrf_protect on any views that use the csrf_token template tag, as well as those that accept the POST data.

I tried to change all the things that the debuger says to but I keep getting the same error. I would like to know if there are any other files that I need to change other than views.py, the template file(.html) and the settings.py file which are included here:

views.py:

```
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from crunchApp.models import Filter
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.core.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.http import Http404    

def results(request):

    c = {}
    c.update(csrf(request))
    return render_to_response('crunchApp/results.html', c)
```

template/test.html

```
    <form name="myform" action="results" method = "post" >{% csrf_token %}
        <fieldset>
            <input type="checkbox" value="total_money" id = "money_check" name="check" /> Filter by Total Money</br>
    </fieldset></form>
```

settings.py

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't need

```
c = {}
c.update(csrf(request))
```

but you do need context_instance=RequestContext(request), as in

```
render_to_response(<template>, <vars>, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```